# In Android webview, how to cross domain?

Tags: android, oauth, webview

I am writing an Android app, in the app I need do Oauth for windows live, while asking user to allow the access, the page is ugly(seems the picture and css not loaded).

In the backend, I get this error:

> 12-06 16:17:14.670: WARN/DomainNameValidator(3646): DomainNameValidator.matchDns(): java.io.IOException: DNS name must start with a letter: cdn.dc2files.*.livefilestore-int.com

It looks like the css file and picture are loaded from a different domain, however the validator doesn't allow cross domain.

Does anyone know how to cross domain in the Webview?

Or other solution to make the page looks well?